# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS cannot be found on kubeflow

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I follow the [tutorial](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/gcp-e2e/) for building kubeflow on GCP.

At the last step, I got stuck at "Check the permissions for your training component".

After setting these secretName and secretMountPath.

```
kustomize edit add configmap mnist-map-training --from-literal=secretName=user-gcp-sa
kustomize edit add configmap mnist-map-training --from-literal=secretMountPath=/var/secrets
```

and run

```
kustomize build . |kubectl apply -f -
```

I got the error:

> Error: field specified in var '{GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ~G_v1_ConfigMap {data.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}}' not found in
>   corresponding resource
>       error: no objects passed to apply

I cannot find my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS at /var/secrets in my local machine, but I think kubeflow will automatic create for me based on this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#built-in-secrets).

Or maybe because I use "Authenticating with username and password" for authenticating kubeflow?

Comment: I don't know the context, but do you have any rule preventing your nodes from accessing google metadata server (169.254.169.254)?

Comment: @suren I didn't setting any rule. I think the main problem is the kubeflow cluster don't have the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in /var/secrets.

Comment: What's output of `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` ?

Comment: @ThinkFloyd Thanks for advice, the reason is the tutorial didn't set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS path for remote cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at [here](https://github.com/kubeflow/examples/tree/master/mnist).

```
kustomize edit add configmap mnist-map-monitoring --from-literal=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/var/secrets/user-gcp-sa.json
```

In original [tutorial](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/gcp-e2e/), lacking of this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jim ! Yes this fixed the issue for me after I cleaned up all my local changes.

Comment: @ThinkFloyd ha it's good to hear it help. Btw, do you encounter this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322632/distributed-tensorflow-in-kubeflow-notfounderror) in the same tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Kubeflow kustomize is under dev and expect to be mature in next release v0.6.0.