# Distributed Tensorflow in Kubeflow - NotFoundError

Tags: tensorflow, kubeflow

I follow the [tutorial](https://github.com/kubeflow/examples/tree/master/mnist) for building kubeflow on GCP.

At the last step, after deploying [the code](https://github.com/kubeflow/examples/blob/master/mnist/model.py) and training with CPU.

```
kustomize build . |kubectl apply -f -
```

The distributed tensorflow encounter this issue

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:
>   /tmp/tmprIn1Il/model.ckpt-1_temp_a890dac1971040119aba4921dd5f631a; No
>   such file or directory
>   [[Node: save/SaveV2 =
>   SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64],
>   _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save/ShardedFilename, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices,
>   conv_layer1/conv2d/bias, conv_layer1/conv2d/kernel,
>   conv_layer2/conv2d/bias, conv_layer2/conv2d/kernel, dense/bias,
>   dense/kernel, dense_1/bias, dense_1/kernel, global_step)]]

I found the similar [bug report](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6374#issuecomment-269509857) but don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the bug report.

> You can work around this problem by using a shared filesystem (e.g.
>   HDFS, GCS, or an NFS mount at the same mount point) on the workers and
>   the parameter servers.

Just put the data on GCS and it work fine.

model.py

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

# tfds works in both Eager and Graph modes
tf.enable_eager_execution()

# See available datasets
print(tfds.list_builders())

ds_train, ds_test = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=["train", "test"], data_dir="gs://kubeflow-tf-bucket", batch_size=-1)
ds_train = tfds.as_numpy(ds_train)
ds_test = tfds.as_numpy(ds_test)

(x_train, y_train) = ds_train['image'], ds_train['label']
(x_test, y_test) = ds_test['image'], ds_test['label']
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
print(model.evaluate(x_test, y_test))
```